# Accept and submit minibuffer isearch result with a single keypress

Tags: minibuffer, isearch

I like how Bash handles i-search: `C-r`, type some characters, `C-r` a couple more times to find the desired command, then hit `Return` and the command is executed.

If I want to edit the command before it's executed, I type any of `C-e`, `C-a`, `C-l`, `<left>`, `<right>`, which exits isearch, leaving the result on the command line.

I love using `C-r` to search Emacs' minibuffer history, but having to hit `Return` once to accept the search result and a second time to submit it is annoying. I guess it's partly psychological...

- *Me (searching)*: There, that's the one. Enter!
- *Emacs*: um, *this* one?
- *Me (eyeroll)*: Yes, that one. Enter.

I want to fix this. `Return` is bound to `isearch-exit` in `overriding-terminal-local-map`. This appears to be the case both inside and outside the minibuffer. It also seems that the aforementioned map is not defined until you've entered isearch.

My current solution:

```
(defun ivan/isearch-exit ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-exit)
  (if (minibuffer-window-active-p (selected-window))
      (minibuffer-complete-and-exit)))

(defun ivan/remap-isearch-exit ()
  (define-key
    overriding-terminal-local-map
    [remap isearch-exit]
    #'ivan/isearch-exit))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook #'ivan/remap-isearch-exit)
```

So far, this seems to work, but is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: FWIW: You might want to try [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_History_Enhancements#MatchHistoricalCandidates) for a more powerful and more flexible way to access previously used minibuffer inputs.

Comment: Bind your command in `isearch-mode-map`.

Comment: @politza That was the first thing I tried, but it seems `overriding-terminal-local-map` takes precedence over `isearch-mode-map` (which makes sense, given its name).

Comment: I should have guessed so.